# How to get circular graph coordinates of a clicked position

Tags: python, onclick, turtle-graphics

I've created a turtle program in python that creates a color wheel around position (0,0). Here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/xDyddfwa. What I would like to be able to do, is be able to click somewhere on the wheel, and be told how many degrees around the circle the color I clicked is. So basically, instead of Cartesian coordinates, I would like circular graph coordinates. If you ran the color wheel program, it would prompt you to enter a number. If entered 6, it would draw a six-color wheel. You will see that red is on the bottom to the right. I would like to be able to click that, and get 0. Then if I click on the yellow, I would get 1, etc. Also how could I store that value to a variable. (I've been having trouble using onclick()) Please help.

Comment: always in question put code and full error message.

Comment: to run this outside `IDLE` you need `done()` or `mainloop()`. `turtle` and `IDLE` use `tkinter` which needs  `mainloop()` to work. When you run in `IDLE` then it run own `mainloop()` and this code works - but outside IDLE it doesn't draw circle.

Comment: to make code more readable use: empty line before `def` and `if __name__`, space after comma. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

`onclick()` works only if you click on turtle. Use `onscreenclick(callback)` to execute function on every click. It gives you `(x,y)` so you have to calculate `angle` in degrees and then convert angle to correct number. It is not ideal because it calculate number for every click on screen, not only on colors.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
import colorsys
import math

def arch(radius, degree, width, colour):
    color(colour)
    pd()
    begin_fill()
    circle(radius, degree)
    lt(90)
    fd(width)
    lt(90)
    circle(-radius+width, degree)
    lt(90)
    fd(width)
    lt(90)
    end_fill()
    pu()
    circle(radius, degree)
    pd()

def start():
    pu()
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    lt(90)

def startover():
    reset()
    main()

def get_number(x, y):
    # inform function to use global variable
    #global k

    angle = 180 - math.degrees(math.atan2(x,y))

    angle %= 360

    number = int(angle*k/360)

    print('Pos:', x, y, 'Angle:', angle, 'Number:', number)

def main():
    # Inform function to use global variable when you use `=`
    # You will need this value in `get_number
    global k

    s = turtle.Screen()
    #t = turtle.Turtle()

    s.colormode(255)
    tracer(False)

    reset()
    start()

    k = int(numinput(""," How many colors?"))

    colorlist = []

    for i in range(k):
        colorlist.append(list(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(i/k,1,255)))

    print(colorlist)

    for i in range(len(colorlist)):
        for j in range(len(colorlist[i])):
            colorlist[i][j] = int(colorlist[i][j])
        arch(200, 360/k, 100, (colorlist[i]))

    onkey(startover, "a")
    onscreenclick(get_number)
    #listen()

    done()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

**EDIT:** `turtle` uses `tkinter` in background, and `tkinter` is more powerfull - ie. it has functions to draw `arc`, `pieslice`, etc. - and you can assign mouse click to every object on canvas.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
import colorsys

def get_number(event, number):
    #print('widget:', event.widget)
    print('number:', number)

def main():

    s = turtle.Screen()

    s.colormode(255)

    k = int(numinput("","How many colors?"))

    colorlist = []

    for i in range(k):
        color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(i/k,1,255)
        color = (int(color[0]), int(color[1]), int(color[2]))
        colorlist.append(color)

    canvas = s.getcanvas()

    for i in range(len(colorlist)):
        # convert (255, 255, 255) into '#ffffff'
        color = s._colorstr(colorlist[i])

        # create `arc`
        part_id = canvas.create_arc(-200, -200, 200, 200, outline=color, start=(i*360/k)-90, extent=360/k, width=100, style='arc')

        # assign button click to this part with `number`
        canvas.tag_bind(part_id, '<Button>', lambda event, number=i:get_number(event, number))

    done()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

effbot.org: [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: I believe this produces incorrect results -- based on the OP's description of the problem, on a six segment wheel, the color red should be between 0 degrees and 60 degrees, not 120 degrees and 180 degrees as this prints to the console.  Also red should be number 0, not 2 and 3 as it is here.

Comment: @cdlane you are right :) I didn't check colors, I expected standard system with 0 degrees at top. But with small modification it works better.

Comment: I added example with `canvas` from `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the other answer, based on the OP's code, makes the problem more complicated than necessary while producing incorrect results.  Below's my attempt to simplify the logic and produce correct values (e.g. red is 0, yellow is 1, etc. on a 6 segment HSB circle.)  I've rotated the circle 90 degrees to make the math align better.  Also, the results are printed in the center of the circle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb
import math

FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

RADIUS = 200
WIDTH = 100

last_result = ()  # Also how could I store that value to a variable?

def arch(radius, width, colorlist):

    ''' Creates a color wheel around position (0,0) '''

    degree = 360 / len(colorlist)
    inner_radius = radius - width

    turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(radius)
    turtle.setheading(90)

    for color in colorlist:
        turtle.color(color)

        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.circle(radius, degree)
        position = turtle.position()
        heading = turtle.heading()
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.circle(-inner_radius, degree)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.setposition(position)
        turtle.setheading(heading)

def get_number(x, y, turtle, segments):

    '''
    Click somewhere on the wheel, and be told how many degrees around the
    circle the color you clicked. For a six-color wheel, if you click on
    red, you get 0. If you click on yellow, you get 1, etc.
    '''

    global last_result

    if (RADIUS - WIDTH) ** 2 < x ** 2 + y ** 2 < RADIUS ** 2:

        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x)) % 360

        number = int(angle * segments / 360)

        turtle.undo()
        turtle.write('{} ({:5.1f}\u00b0)'.format(number, angle), align='center', font=FONT)

        last_result = (number, angle)

def main():

    screen = Screen()

    segments = int(screen.numinput('Color Wheel', 'How many colors?'))

    colorlist = [hsv_to_rgb(i / segments, 1.0, 1.0) for i in range(segments)]

    screen.tracer(False)
    arch(RADIUS, WIDTH, colorlist)
    screen.tracer(True)

    magic_marker = Turtle(visible=False)
    magic_marker.penup()
    magic_marker.sety(-FONT_SIZE/2)
    magic_marker.write('', align='center', font=FONT)

    screen.onscreenclick(lambda x, y, t=magic_marker, s=segments: get_number(x, y, t, s))

    screen.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've changed the color logic to 0.0 to 1.0 to simplify the code and made it only respond when you click on the color wheel itself, not just anywhere in the window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! Wish I could program like that. Helped me so much!

Comment: I have another question. How could I make onscreenclick() stop listening. I would like to be able to click twice, get those two numbers, and then move on to some other function or something else. FTR: I have tried to figure it out on my own and have researched, but as usual, could find nothing. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JoshHenderson, like most turtle event handlers, supplying `None` as the event handler will turn it off:  `screen.onscreenclick(None)`  This is spelled out in the Python turtle documentation which is easily found with a simple web search.